# Add tabindex / focus to buttons in Safari without changing default browser preferences

Tags: html, safari, keyboard, accessibility, tabindex

When navigating a form using the keyboard, button elements don't gain focus in Safari (tested in v8.0 on Yosemite). This is unless tabbing is explicitly turned under Preferences --> Advanced. Is there any way to get around this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <form action="">
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" />
      <button>Button</button>
      <input type="text" />
      <button type="button">Button</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

http://codepen.io/alexandtheweb/pen/raQrxw

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to get around this. The user needs to enable these preferences in order for tabbing to work correctly.

Comment: Does anyone know the rationale behind this?  It's awful for accessibility, no?

Answer (score 7):

Safari behavior is quite different from others browsers. By default you can focus to all clickable elements with "Option(/Alt) + Tab" shortcut. Tab will only focus text field unless the option you mentionned is turned on.

See for instance, the following help page, next to the "Highlight the next item on a webpage" section.
https://support.apple.com/kb/PH17148?locale=en_US

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick fix if you are using jquery:

```
$('body').on('keydown',function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 9){
        var $focused = $(':focus');
        var inputs = $('input:not([type="hidden"]),select,textarea,button');
        inputs.eq(inputs.index($focused[0])+1).focus();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```